# Laravel Query Ajax Update

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello someone can you explain me how to update  with Ajax!!

I use laravel

I want html and ajax only

My routes

```
Route::post('/post/homepage', 'AdminController@HomePage');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should name your route:

```
Route::post('/post/homepage', 'AdminController@HomePage')->name('post.create');
```

Then, create your HTML form :

```
<form id="myForm">
{{csrf_field()}}
<label for="name">Article Name :</label>
<input id="name" name="articleName" type="text" required>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Note: `{{csrf_field()}}` will generate the Form CSRF field. Or you can use instead :

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

I'll use jQuery to handle ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Do not submit the form
            var dataflow=$(this).serialize(); //Get the inputs value
            $.post('{{route('post.create')}}', dataflow, function (data){ //post.create is the route name
                //The request is done, do something with the server response
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: my second input not change but first yeah how to fix that?

Comment: i must click double save button to update and second input

Comment: I don't understand the problem, please show me the code.